# Rails GET from json data ActiveResource

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have small school project.

My roommate create an application which simulates a burger order system. But I had to create an delivery service application.

Our idea was like this:

He gives me `JSON` data from his order page and I read this data and display in my admin page.

This is the link where `JSON` data is parsed https://eburger-appzz.rhcloud.com/public-orders

How can I display this data in my application?

I tried to connect to it with `ActiveResource` like this ->

`self.site="http://eburger-appzz.rhcloud.com/public-orders"`

but I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions, what would be the best way to GET this data from server?

Comment: I am not sure why people are down voting this question. Please cite the reason to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly tried out the URI that you have given and was able to get it working with following code.

```
class PublicOrder < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site="http://eburger-appzz.rhcloud.com/"
  self.element_name = "public-orders"
end
```

and to fetch all public orders

```
public_orders = PublicOrder.find(:all)
```

listed orders.

BTW we have been using ActiveResource for a while now and to be able to use ActiveResource, consider implementing REST service as per their [philosophy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activeresource/README_rdoc.html)

Comment: @karlis Sure. BTW I forgot to mention you have a typo in your code in OP. Instead of `http://https://` you needed to mention `http` in `self.site`

Comment: Maybe you could recommend me what would be the best way to send back information when the delivery is completed?

Comment: Do you mean physically pizza is delivered, and entry is made in to the system/database? In any case a REST `end point` would be required check the delivery status. For example and service provider should provide an endpoint like `http://eburger-appzz.rhcloud.com/pizza/1/status` which should return JSON like `{status : "pending"}`. Its a larger design question, you may want to discuss or read about it.